# Ad hiding extra space in the view

Tags: android, admob

I am making an app in which i want to show ad in the layout.When i do that,everything works fine when the ad is visible,but when when the ad is not visible,it still occupies the space in the layout/view.Please tell me how to solve this problem.

This is layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="90.0dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1.0dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="1.0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="-2.0dip"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:fadeScrollbars="true"
            android:fadingEdge="none" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/QuestionImageView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/QuestionImageView"
                    android:fadingEdge="vertical"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/questionnumber"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:fadingEdge="vertical"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/question"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tv"
                    android:fadingEdge="vertical"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@color/dark_green" />

                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/question"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/option1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1.0dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/thinnest_blue_gradient" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/option2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1.0dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/thinnest_blue_gradient" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/option3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1.0dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/thinnest_blue_gradient" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/option4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="" />
                </RadioGroup>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativequestion"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/ad"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="a1501e5633125fb"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
            ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, 123456789ABCDEF" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/newquestion"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40.0dip"
            android:layout_above="@id/ad"
            android:background="#ff777777"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/PrevButton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:background="@drawable/ibtn"
                android:onClick="onPrevButtonClick"
                android:text="Prev" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/NextButton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:background="@drawable/ibtn"
                android:onClick="onNextButtonClick"
                android:text="Next" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/SkipButton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:background="@drawable/ibtn"
                android:onClick="onSkipButtonClick"
                android:text="Skip" >
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/SubmitButton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5.0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:background="@drawable/ibtn"
                android:onClick="onSubmitButtonClick"
                android:text="Submit" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>  
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to ask this to your ad provider

Comment: This is not the problem with ad,it must be some problem with the layout itself.

Comment: your scenario is "ad is not visible" but i think it is visible but ad banner did not coming from server that's why it display as black

Comment: yes sir that is the exact problem

Comment: so it is not your problem it is problem of AdMob because AdMob library need to display that Ad banner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be an issue with `View.Invisible` vs `View.Gone`?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ad.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

it should make ad block disappear